# run JavaScript x amount times, each time number in array increase by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, arraylist

this is the html, which I cannot directly change the DOM, but able to modify things like attribute and class only with JS:

```
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_1">
        <img src="/site/images/someimage.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_2">
        <img src="/site/images/someotherimage.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_3">
        <img src="/site/images/somedifferentimage.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
```

trying to use JS to replace the `img src`, so the src name will match the parent `for attribute` value, like

```
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_1">
        <img src="/site/images/label_1.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_2">
        <img src="/site/images/label_2.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_3">
        <img src="/site/images/label_3.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
```

I have this:

```
<script>
let n = ""
let amt = document.getElementsByClassName("layout-choice-thumbnail-label").length;
for (let i = 0; i <= amt; i++) {
    n += i + ', ';
}

var attr = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0].getAttribute("for");
var imgSrc = '../images/content/pagebuilder/' + cardId + '.jpg';
document.querySelectorAll(".child")[0].firstElementChild.setAttribute('src', imgSrc);
</script>
```

which only works for one, how could I change it so every time the page loads, the value inside the `[0]` is increased by 1, or when the whole script loads, all image name matches the `for attribute` from `<div class="parent">`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "when the whole script load". Do you mean it like when your page loads the script? If so, why not simply use a `for` loop for the last 3 lines, like you just above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code edited. :)

```js
let amt = document.getElementsByClassName("child").length;

for (let i = 0; i < amt; i++) {

    var attr = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[i].getAttribute("for")
var imgSrc = '../images/content/pagebuilder/' + attr + '.jpg';
 document.querySelectorAll(".child")[i].firstElementChild.setAttribute('src', imgSrc); 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_1">
        <img src="/site/images/label_1.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_2">
        <img src="/site/images/label_2.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <label class="child" for="label_3">
        <img src="/site/images/label_3.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
```